# Automatically Change High Color 16 Bit to True Color 32 Bit in Advanced Settings --> Monitor Tab through Automated Script

Tags: batch-file, scripting, automation, autohotkey

How to change the Monitor true color to 32 Bit using bacth file (or) Script

Right Click Desktop - > Screen Resolution -> Advanced Settings - > Select Monitor -> Colors -> Select True Color (32 bit).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about using third party applications you can use [QRes](http://qres.software.informer.com/1.1/). ([Source](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/233772-command-line-change-colour-depth.html) Bottom post).

Seems like with it you can do `qres.exe /c:16` or `qres.exe /c:32`

Comment: There is no exe file when i download it from QRes :(

Comment: You can download QRes from the internet. It is a command-line application that can be used in scripts as well. Then place the line above in one script and name it `col16.bat` and the other `col32.bat`. Run when needed. And I am not here for searching for executables for you.... Google for it, and you might find something!